# Method call (that has been defined in fragment) on button click using android data binding in not working.?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want to call `onButtonclick(View v)` using android binding in the layout xml file.

How to achieve button `click` using android binding in this case?
I followed as below but it didn't work. Any suggestions ? Thanks in Advance.

**Layout1.xml**

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="myFrag"
        type="com.myapp.Fragment1" />
</data>
...
<Button
 android:id="@+id/step_button"
 style="@style/button_style"
 android:onClick="@{myFrag :: onButtonclick}"/>
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
.....
public void onButtonclick(View v)
{
  myStdent.setId("No ID");
}
.....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Layout1Binding myBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.layout1.xml, container, false);
myBinding. setMyFrag(this);
```

Above lines of code has solved the problem. I have added these lines in onCreateView.

Comment: setMyFrag().. what is this ?

Comment: In the question , if you can see the layout file , we have a data tag and a variable  ‘myFrag’ of ‘Fragment1’ type. So , setMyFrag() is a setter for that ‘myFrag’ variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing 
http://prntscr.com/fm6yih (init variable for databinding object)

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment layout xml, define a fragment variable. Then in your fragment class, map the xml variable to the fragment using binding.setVariable. Now you should be able to use all fragment variables and methods in xml.

In fragment layout xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.MyFragment">
<data>
    <variable
        name="frag"
        type="com.example.MyFragment" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> frag.yourMethod()}" />
 </RelativeLayout>
 </layout>
```

In fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val inflater = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_my, myFragmentContainer, true)
        binding.setVariable(BR.frag, this@MyFragment)
    }
}
```